# Apostrophes, handling with EXEC

Tags: sql-server

I have the following SQL that I'm needing to run as a part of an exec statement. What I'm struggling with though is getting the apostrophes right. The statement executes fine if I run it by itself with only 1 apostrophe, and I thought having 2 would escape it out allowing it to work.

Any ideas?

```
exec
('
SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(CAST((DATEDIFF(mi,sqlserver_start_time,GetDate())/1440 ) as varchar),''0'') + '' day(s), '','''')
+ COALESCE(NULLIF(CAST(((DATEDIFF(mi,sqlserver_start_time,GetDate())%1440)/60) as varchar),''0'') + '' hour(s), '','''')
+ CAST((DATEDIFF(mi,sqlserver_start_time,GetDate())%60) as varchar) + ''min'' as Uptime
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info) as Uptime,
CAST(LEFT((RIGHT(@@version, LEN(@@version)- 3 -charindex ('' ON '',@@VERSION))),CHARINDEX(''<'',(RIGHT(@@version, LEN(@@version)- 3 -charindex ('' ON '',@@VERSION))),0)-2) as nvarchar(300)) as OS,
cast(serverproperty(''MachineName'') as nvarchar(255)) MachineName,
cast(serverproperty(''ServerName'') as nvarchar(255)) ServerInstanceName,
cast(LEFT(@@VERSION,CHARINDEX(''('',@@VERSION,0)-2) as nvarchar(300)) as Version,
cast(replace(cast(serverproperty(''Edition'')as varchar),''Edition'','''') as varchar(max)) Edition,
cast(serverproperty(''productVersion'') as nvarchar(255)) ProductBuildLevel,
cast(serverproperty(''productLevel'') as nvarchar(255)) SPLevel,
cast(serverproperty(''Collation'') as nvarchar(255)) CollationType,
cast(serverproperty(''IsClustered'') as nvarchar(255)) [IsClustered],
cast((select physical_memory_kb/1024 FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info) as int) AS PhysicalMemory,    
cast((select value from sys.configurations where name = ''min server memory (MB)'') as int) as MinMemory,
cast((select value from sys.configurations where name = ''max server memory (MB)'') as int) as MaxMemory,
cast((select cpu_count FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info) as int) AS LogicalCPUCount,
cast((select hyperthread_ratio FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info) as int) AS HyperthreadRatio,
cast((select cpu_count/hyperthread_ratio FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info) as int) AS PhysicalCPUCount   
')
```

The error I get is:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
```

Comment: It might be helpful for you to print the statement you're trying to execute and manually do a visual scan of it. For example, when I do that, it lets me easily see the error on line 5: `FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info) as Uptime,` is not syntactically correct here. I believe the very start of your query should be `SELECT (SELECT` and you left out the second "select" here. If you adjust that, your query runs fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of errors in the query you posted. Try

```
EXEC ('SELECT COALESCE(NULLIF(CAST((DATEDIFF(mi,sqlserver_start_time,GetDate())/1440 ) as varchar),''0'') + '' day(s), '','''')
+ COALESCE(NULLIF(CAST(((DATEDIFF(mi,sqlserver_start_time,GetDate())%1440)/60) as varchar),''0'') + '' hour(s), '','''')
+ CAST((DATEDIFF(mi,sqlserver_start_time,GetDate())%60) as varchar) + ''min'' as Uptime,
CAST(LEFT((RIGHT(@@version, LEN(@@version)- 3 -charindex ('' ON '',@@VERSION))),CHARINDEX(''<'',(RIGHT(@@version, LEN(@@version)- 3 -charindex ('' ON '',@@VERSION))),0)-2) as nvarchar(300)) as OS,
cast(serverproperty(''MachineName'') as nvarchar(255)) MachineName,
cast(serverproperty(''ServerName'') as nvarchar(255)) ServerInstanceName,
cast(LEFT(@@VERSION,CHARINDEX(''('',@@VERSION,0)-2) as nvarchar(300)) as Version,
cast(replace(cast(serverproperty(''Edition'')as varchar),''Edition'','''') as varchar(max)) Edition,
cast(serverproperty(''productVersion'') as nvarchar(255)) ProductBuildLevel,
cast(serverproperty(''productLevel'') as nvarchar(255)) SPLevel,
cast(serverproperty(''Collation'') as nvarchar(255)) CollationType,
cast(serverproperty(''IsClustered'') as nvarchar(255)) [IsClustered],
cast((select physical_memory_kb/1024 FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info) as int) AS PhysicalMemory,    
cast((select value from sys.configurations where name = ''min server memory (MB)'') as int) as MinMemory,
cast((select value from sys.configurations where name = ''max server memory (MB)'') as int) as MaxMemory,
cast((select cpu_count FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info) as int) AS LogicalCPUCount,
cast((select hyperthread_ratio FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info) as int) AS HyperthreadRatio,
cast((select cpu_count/hyperthread_ratio FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info) as int) AS PhysicalCPUCount   
FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info as Uptime')
```